# What is it called, to extract an address from HTML via NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have 300k+ html documents, which I want to extract postal addresses from. The data is different structures, so regex wont work.

I have done a heap of reading on NLP and NLTK for python, however I am still struggling on where to start with this.

Is this approach called Part-of-Speech Tagging or Chunking / Partial Parsing? I can't find any document on how to actually TAG a page so I can train a model on it, or even what I should be training.

So my questions;

- What is this approach called?
- How can I tag some documents to train from

Comment: Are you talking about looking for postal addresses?

Comment: Yes that is correct, eg http://web.cs.dal.ca/~zyu/research/Thesis.pdf

Comment: Could you post some sample input?

Answer (score 2):

**Qn: Which NLP task is closely related with this task?**

**Ans:** The task of detecting postal address can be viewed as a [Name-Entity Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER) task. But I suggest viewing the task as simply [sequence labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling) on html (i.e. your input data) and then perform some standard machine learning [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning).

**Qn: How can I tag some documents to use as training data?**

**An:** What you can do is to:

1. Label each word or each line as **B** egin **I** nside or **O** utside
2. Choose a [supervised classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning) method
3. Decide what are the features (here's some hint: [Feature selection](http://www.improvedoutcomes.com/docs/WebSiteDocs/Classification_and_Prediction/SLAM/An_Introduction_to_Classification.htm))
4. Build the model (basically just run the classification software with the configured
   features)
5. Voila, output should give you **B** and **I** and
   **O** , then just delete all the instances labelled **O**  and you will be left with the lines/words that are addresses

Answer (score 1):

Apple calls their software that does this "Data Detectors" (be careful, it's patented -- they won an [injunction](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/12/19/itc_grants_injunction_over_apple_data_detectors_patent_against_htc_android_phones.html) against HTC Android phones over this). More generally, I think this application is called [Information Extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction).

Answer (score 1):

Strip the text out of the HTML page (unless there is a way from the  HTML to identify the address text such as div with a particular class) then build a set of rules that match the address formats used.

If there are postal addresses in several countries then the formats may be markedly different but within a country, the format is the same (with some tweaks) or it is not valid.

Within the US, for example, addresses are 3 or 4 lines (including the person). There is usually a zip code (5 digits optionally followed by four more).  Other countries have postal codes in different formats.

Unless your goal is 100% accuracy on all addresses then you probably should aim for extracting as many addresses as you can within the budget for the task.

It doesn't seem like a task for NLP unless you want to use Named Entity identification to find  cities, countries etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is called information extraction, but that's a very, very broad concept. Luckily your task is more limited (street addresses), but you don't give a lot of information:

1. What countries are the addresses in? An address in Tokyo looks very different from one in Cleveland. Your odds of succeeding are much better if you're interested in addresses from a limited number of countries-- you can develop a solution from each of them. If we're talking about a *very* limited number, you could code a recognizer [manually](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/wiki/USAAddressExtraction).
2. What kind of webpages are we talking about? Are they a random collection, or can you group them into a limited number of websites and formats? Where do the addresses appear? (I.e., are there any contextual clues you can use to zero in on them?)

I'll take a worse-case scenario for question 2: The pages are completely disparate and the address could be anywhere. Not sure what the state of the art is, but I'd approach it as a chunking problem.

To get any kind of decent results, you need a training set. At a minimum, a *large* collection of addresses from the same locations and in the same style (informal, incomplete, complete) as the addresses you'll be extracting. Then you can try to coax decent performance out of a chunker (probably with post-processing).

PS. I wouldn't just discard the html mark-up. It contains information about document structure which could be useful. I'd add structural mark-up (paragraphs, emphasis, headings, lists, displays) before you throw out the html tags.